# Imputing a categorical variable with MICE but restricting the possible values

Tags: r, categorical-data, imputation, r-mice

I have a categorical variable, `var1`, that can take on values of `"W"`, `"B"`, `"A"`, `"M"`, `"N"` or `"P"`. I want to impute the missings, but I know that the missing values cannot be `"W"` or `"B"`, because those people said that they do not belong in that category. I want to impute `var1` but force mice to only choose from everything except `"B"` or `"W"`.

Here is sample code for you to use:

```r
df <- data.frame(
  age        = c(24, 37, 58, 65, 70, 84, 56, 36, 48, 23, 15), 
  var1       = c("B", "W", NA, "A", NA, "P", "N", NA, "M", NA, "B"), 
  var1categ  = c(0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0),
  ht         = c(156, 169, 180, 175, 168, 165, 171, 158, 160, 175, 160)
)

imp <- mice(df, remove_collinear = FALSE)
```

Thank you for your help and please let me know if you need more information.

Answer (score 1):

I think the following approach should work:

1. Completely remove all "W" and "B" cases from your dataset.
2. Perform the imputation with mice

Since you only have missing data in var1 (where you are sure that no W and B is present), you don't need the "W" and "B" cases anyway.

Note: Approach would be different, if you also have missing data in other columns.

Comment: The problem with this approach is that we have less power. It's not the preferable solution for that reason. I would prefer something that allows me to use the available data but with arguments that will be used to avoid the mentioned problem.

Comment: I don't think you have less power. Since the data you delete anyway wouldn't have been used for anything (you said this cases can't occur for the NAs). How do you think this data could be employed in this case modeling wise? As I said this would be different, if other variables were also missing.

Comment: +1 Although a third step would be to reinsert these cases in the imputed datasets after imputation. Maybe the OP means that there is a loss in power for subsequent analyses, which would be true if these cases are deleted entirely. For the imputation process power should not be influenced.

Answer (score 1):

I think @stats0007 is correct but you will have to re-insert the deleted rows in all the m imputed datasets (in your case, all 5 imputed datasets). Using your example, this is how I would do it.

First remove all "W" and "B" cases and store in a seperate data.frame

```
df=data.frame(age=c(24,37,58,65,70,84, 56, 36, 48,23,15), 
              var1 =c("B","W", NA, "A",NA, "P","N", NA, "M",NA, "B"), 
              var1categ=c(0,0, 1, 1, 1,1,1,1,1,1, 0),
              ht = c(156, 169, 180, 175, 168, 165, 171, 158, 160, 175, 160))

df[which(df$var1 != "B" & df$var1 != "W" | is.na(df$var1)),]  # Keep rows not containing B and W
df3 <- df[df$var1 %in% c("B","W"),] # Store deleted rows
```

Next, impute the data without these deleted cases. The logged event is because one of your variables is now a constant.

```
library(mice)
imp=mice(df2, remove_collinear = FALSE)
```

Finally, insert the deleted cases back into each imputed datasets 1:5. There is probably a better way, but a for loop can work.

```
# Create an empty data frame
data <- data.frame()

# For each imputation 1:5
for(i in unique(comp_imp$.imp)){

  # Create a .imp variable and .id variable in the dataset with the deleted rows
  df3$.imp <- i
  df3$.id <- (max(comp_imp$.id)+1):(max(comp_imp$.id)+nrow(df3))
  df3 <- df3[,c(5,6,1:4)]

  # Bind the new rows to the imputed dataset
  df_temp <- rbind(comp_imp[comp_imp$.imp == i,],df3)
  data <- rbind(data, df_temp)
}
```

`data` now contains all the imputed values and the original "B" and "W" observed values. You could transform this back to a `mids` object for further use in the `mice` package.

```
# Transform into a mids object for further use
imp_tot <- as.mids(data)
```